# How to get column name by index using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How can I get a column name by its index using sql query in command line?

I expect something like `show columns from my_table where col_index = 2;`

I found many answers about how to show all columns but there's no answer on how to get exact column name by its position in the table.

Comment: do you mean  COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION ?

Comment: @scaisEdge since it represents the column position then yes :)

Comment: @Martin It's not a duplicate. Compare questions carefully.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate guys. He wants 1 column name coming back. Even though he wrote it confusingly imo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use table `information_schema.columns`

```
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'my_table_name' and ordinal_position = 2;
```

Comment: Thx, that works :)

Comment: glad it works :-)

Comment: Warning: if your database contains more than one schema and each can contain the same table name the above will return more than one row. You can refine the query: `... where table_name = 'my_table_name' and table_schema='my_schema_name' and ordinal_position = 2`

Answer (score 0):

You can select from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and use `limit`

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
limit 1, 1;
```